# should i convert json data in hindi using php

Tags: php, json, laravel

Currently i am making app i have saved all data in english and i am using laravel framework as backend so i want when app is requested for data it should convert data in to hindi. Can anyone help me:
Suppose this is my data:-

```
enter code here
"data": [
{
  "id": 4,
  "Name": "Kedarnath",
 }
```

And i want to convert like this:-

```
enter code here
"data": [
{
  "id": 4,
  "Name": "केदारनाथ",
```

}

I want when application is requested for data it should be converted in to hindi can anayone help me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you asking how to convert the string `Kedarnath` into `केदारनाथ`? How would you do this using pen and paper?

Answer (score 0):

use Localization module of Laravel. You can store the English name key as the key in localized array and the value of that key in Hindi. And then Laravel will automatically convert as required. You just need to maintain the array of English to Hindi. Check the below URL for more information.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/localization

Comment: but i have lot of english name . so i have to mention all the name there it is to complex part

Comment: Every word that you want to show in hindi must be converted from English to Hindi. I repeat, each and every word. Although in your code files you will write the english keys and then Laravel's localization will handle the rest.